# Set VM Option if it isn't empty

Tags: install4j

In my install4j installer I set VM option from installer variable:

```
${installer:proxyHostVM}
```

Can I do it only if variable available and isn't empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the "Condition expression" property of the "Add VM options" action that you use to set this VM parameter:

```java
String value = (String)context.getVariable("proxyHostVM");
return value != null && !((String)value).isEmpty()
```